# Tier 2 dependent child and ILR

Tags: uk-visa

We have a child born in UK. We have applied for her Tier 2 dependent visa and she has a valid Tier 2 dependent visa till end of July-2018.

Now we have our ILR but it takes few months to get my child citizenship. I wonder if can we use her Tier 2 dependent visa with our ILR to a two weeks holiday trip abroad?

Thanks.

Comment: Be prepared to be asked why you didn't apply for the child's ILR at the same time as yours and have your Tier 2 documentation with you when you return.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The visa is valid, and you can even extend it as long as you acquired ILR via the Tier 2 PBS route.

Comment: Tried to make this as wordy as I could. Not so easy with these straightforward answers....